# HTTPS/SSL not working with Cups

Tags: ssl, cups

I have a site

mysite.com

and a printer

mysite.com:631/printers/myprinter

Well, https:// www.mysite.com works perfectly and is validated, but https:// www.mysite.com:631/printers/myprinter won't. It says that the connection is not secured and I cannot install the printer.

This is what I have in conf.d in my CUPS server:

```
DefaultEncryption Required
ServerCertificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite/cert.pem
ServerKey /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite/privkey.pem
SSLPort 443
```

Any help making the printer and the site https?

Comment: if you configured cups to use port 443, why are you trying to access it via port 631?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider CUPS server is 631 by default. I tried with and without SSLPort but it doesn't work anyway. Guess you are onto something. I am a programmer not a sysadmin...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy your SSL (example LetsEncrypt ) to cups directory, as shown below:

```
cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/fullchain.pem >> /etc/cups/ssl/server.crt
cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/privkey.pem >> /etc/cups/ssl/server.key
```

restart cups-server:

```
systemctl restart cups  # on CentOS
```

Answer (score 1):

So you also need to make sure in /etc/cups/ssl there are alone two files.
server.key and server.crt adding any extra files to this directory broke ssl for me.

But make sure they are links to your lets encrypt folder as other have said.

Answer (score 0):

Gonna add some notes while I'm here.

I am using Nginx to forward a pretty domain over the CUPS IP/port.

This [site](https://www.robpeck.com/2020/09/proxying-cups-ipp-using-nginx/) here (not related to me) made it click.

Anyway in my nginx config I have a location block like this:

```
location /printers {
    // this is the info that came from the site mentioned
    proxy_pass http://localhost:631;
    proxy_set_header Host "127.0.0.1";
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

I generated my cert with Lets Encrypt, goes to same folder as mentioned by SchiWaGoA
I used `symlink` instead of `cat` as I had permission problems eg:

```
ln -s /lets-encrypt-path/fullchain.pem /cups-ssl-path/server.crt (same as above)
```

`cupds.conf`

I have `Listen localhost:631` on

```
<Location />
  Order allow, deny
  Allow from @LOCAL
</Location>
```

At the bottom of this file I added the encryption stuff as mine didn't have it

```
DefaultEncryption Required
ServerCertificate /etc/cups/ssl/server.crt
ServerKey /etc/cups/ssl/server.key
```

And that's it, was able to add the printer on my Windows 10 client using shared hostname url with the `https://example.com/printers/printer-name` url scheme and then MS PS driver.

Note. I'm not 100% on the `<Location />` block so check if it suits your needs.

Will add atm I'm noticing the server keeps going down, unlike my previous non https CUPS, odd.

Looks like you need to [add this line](https://www.papercut.com/kb/Main/CupsHostError) to `cupsd.conf`

`ServerAlias *`

One of my problems anyway, will monitor to see if it improves.

Seems to have improved after I restarted, will report back if I discover some specific reason it was going down often. The non-https one has been up for months.

I ended up modifying the systemd file

```
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
```

Also the cert lines are supposed to go in `cups-files.conf` instead of `cupsd.conf` according to the debug logs of cups. Not a problem now but will be in the future.